# Fast mechanism to activate iOS app from background

Tags: ios, iphone

Generally, when an app is in background, the user can't see any of it's content or controllers on the iOS screen.  The primary way to bring an app back is to hit the home button and then select the app.
Our users want to be able to get super fast access to our app, without having to go through this process.  For example, if they are using the messaging app or playing some game, they'd like to be able to get back to our app super quickly and easily. Is there a way to do this?
Some possible examples:

1) Create a button that stays on the screen (on top of other content) even when the app is in the background?

2) Reassign one of the buttons to bring the app back?

3) Use swipe or gesture or voice recognition to bring the app back (e.g. on shake, particular word)?

4) Some other way to do this.

This would require both technical feasibility and that it remain an app that Apple would approve for general app store release.

Thanks

PS 
Whether this is actually possible/how to do it = helpful.
Why you think that this is a bad idea = not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 and 3 are not possible if you want your app available in the App Store.

The once way I can imagine is using a [Today Widget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html), so the client by sliding down the Today and tapping the widget can go back to the app, even show relevant information in that widget. Is quite faster than using home button.